# Parallel for vs omp simd: when to use each?

Tags: c++, c, performance, openmp, simd

[OpenMP 4.0](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0RC1_final.pdf) introduces a new construct called "omp simd". What is the benefit of using this construct over the old "parallel for"? When would each be a better choice over the other?

EDIT:
Here is an interesting [paper](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-30961-8_5.pdf) related to the SIMD directive.

Comment: openmp was SIMD up uintil version 3.0, then they dropped that concept. I guess the new pragma is for backwards compatibility with old code that relied on some aspects of SIMD. shouldn't the openmp docs have something to say about that?

Comment: It's not `parallel simd`; you use `parallel` _or_ `simd`, which hints at the distinction.   See below.

Comment: @JD: That was a typo, of course. Fixed, thanks

Comment: OpenMP till 3.0 was _NOT_ SIMD. It was only threading and had nothing like SIMD. Speaking CPU: Threading (OMP <=3.0, `parallel for`) is threads/distribution over cores, SIMD (OMP >=4.0, `simd) is vector/AVX/distribution IN a core. This just as a note for future readers.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The linked-to standard is relatively clear (p 13, lines 19+20)

> When any thread encounters a simd construct, the iterations of the
>   loop associated with the construct can be executed by the SIMD lanes
>   that are available to the thread.

`SIMD` is a sub-thread thing.  To make it more concrete, on a CPU you could imagine using `simd` directives to specifically request *vectorization* of chunks of loop iterations that individually belong to the same *thread*.  It's exposing the multiple levels of parallelism that exist within a single multicore processor, in a platform-independent way.  See for instance the discussion (along with the accelerator stuff) on this [intel blog post](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/11/05/openmp-40-may-offer-important-solutions-for-targeting-and-vectorization).

So basically, you'll want to use `omp parallel` to distribute work onto different threads, which can then migrate to multiple cores; and you'll want to use `omp simd` to make use of vector pipelines (say) within each core.  Normally `omp parallel` would go on the "outside" to deal with coarser-grained parallel distribution of work and `omp simd` would go around tight loops inside of that to exploit fine-grained parallelism.

Answer (score 57):

A simple answer:

OpenMP only used to exploit multiple threads for multiple cores. This new `simd` extention allows you to explicitly use **SIMD instructions** on modern CPUs, such as Intel's AVX/SSE and ARM's NEON.

(Note that a SIMD instruction is executed in a single thread and a single core, by design. However, the meaning of SIMD can be quite expanded for GPGPU. But, but I don't think you need to consider GPGPU for OpenMP 4.0.)

So, once you know SIMD instructions, you can use this new construct.

---

In a modern CPU, roughly there are three types of parallelism: (1) instruction-level parallelism (ILP), (2) thread-level parallelism (TLP), and (3) SIMD instructions (we could say this is vector-level or so).

ILP is done automatically by your out-of-order CPUs, or compilers. You can exploit TLP using OpenMP's `parallel for` and other threading libraries. So, what about SIMD? Intrinsics were a way to use them (as well as compilers' automatic vectorization). OpenMP's `simd` is a new way to use SIMD.

Take a very simple example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  A[i] = B[i] + C[i];
```

The above code computes a sum of two N-dimensional vectors. As you can easily see, there is no [(loop-carried) data dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dependency) on the array `A[]`. This loop is [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel).

There could be multiple ways to parallelize this loop. For example, until OpenMP 4.0, this can be parallelized using only `parallel for` construct. Each thread will perform `N/#thread` iterations on multiple cores.

However, you might think using multiple threads for such simple addition would be a overkill. That is why there is vectorization, which is mostly implemented by SIMD instructions.

Using a SIMD would be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N/8; ++i)
  VECTOR_ADD(A + i, B + i, C + i);
```

This code assumes that (1) the SIMD instruction (`VECTOR_ADD`) is 256-bit or 8-way (8 * 32 bits); and (2) `N` is a multiple of 8.

An 8-way SIMD instruction means that 8 items in a vector can be executed in a single machine instruction. Note that Intel's latest AVX provides such 8-way (32-bit * 8 = 256 bits) vector instructions.

In SIMD, you still use a single core (again, this is only for conventional CPUs, not GPU). But, you can use a hidden parallelism in hardware. Modern CPUs dedicate hardware resources for SIMD instructions, where each SIMD *lane* can be executed in parallel.

You can use thread-level parallelism at the same time. The above example can be further parallelized by `parallel for`.

(However, I have a doubt how many loops can be really transformed to SIMDized loops. The OpenMP 4.0 specification seems a bit unclear on this. So, real performance and practical restrictions would be dependent on actual compilers' implementations.)

---

To summarize, `simd` construct allows you to use SIMD instructions, in turn, more parallelism can be exploited along with thread-level parallelism. However, I think actual implementations would matter.

Comment: "But, but I don't think you need to consider GPGPU for OpenMP 4.0." As a matter of fact, one does - there is a proposed support for GPGPU (and other kinds of accelerators) in OpenMP 4.0, but it is in a separate [TR](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/TR1_167.pdf) and not part of the main text (think they did it because the text was not nearly as polished as required in order to be included in the main review text about the time when the SC'12 conference took place).

Comment: "simd construct allows you to use SIMD instructions" falsely implies that not using the simd construct disallows the use of SIMD instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers aren't required to make simd optimization in a parallel region conditional on presence of the simd clause.  Compilers I'm familiar with continue to support nested loops, parallel outer, vector inner, in the same way as before.
In the past, OpenMP directives were usually taken to prevent loop-switching optimizations involving the outer parallelized loop (multiple loops with collapse clause).  This seems to have changed in a few compilers.
OpenMP 4 opens up new possibilities including optimization of a parallel outer loop with a non-vectorizable inner loop, by a sort of strip mining, when omp parallel do [for] simd is set.  ifort sometimes reports it as outer loop vectorization when it is done without the simd clause.  It may then be optimized for a smaller number of threads than the omp parallel do simd, which seems to need more threads than the simd vector width to pay off.  Such a distinction might be inferred, as, without the simd clause, the compiler is implicitly asked to optimize for a loop count such as 100 or 300, while the simd clause requests unconditional simd optimization. 
gcc 4.9 omp parallel for simd looked quite effective when I had a 24-core platform.